# JS Slideshow Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, navigation, slideshow

I am making a simple slideshow from a tutorial: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-sliding-feature-slideshow-with-jquery

I got most of it working, except when i click on the nav buttons, it stays on the same first button, and the screen goes down to the top of the image.

LIVE DEMO: http://epicureancateringaz.com/New/new1

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");
$("#slideshow-nav").css("visability", "visable");
$("#slideshow-nav a[href=#photos1]").addClass("active");

$("#slideshow-nav").localScroll({
    target:'#slideshow', axis: 'x'
});

$("#slideshow-nav a").click(function(){
    $("#slideshow-nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
});
```

```
//css
#slideshow{
width:1000px;
height:320px;
margin:auto;
box-shadow:0px 0px 80px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 80px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 80px #000;
}
#slideshow ul{
width:4000px;
list-style:none;
}
#slideshow ul li{
float:left; 
}
#slideshow-nav{
width:250px;
margin:0 auto 200px auto;   
}
#slideshow-nav ul{
list-style:none;    
}
#slideshow-nav ul li{
float:left; 
}
#slideshow-nav ul li a{
display:block;
width:30px;
height:30px;
float:left;
margin:0 10px;
background-color:#fff;
border-radius:30px; 
-moz-border-radius:30px;
-webkit-border-radius:30px; 
box-shadow:0px 0px 30px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px #000;
}
#slideshow-nav ul li a:hover, #slideshow-nav ul li a.active{
background-color:#a89d8a;
}
```

```
//html
<div id="slideshow">
        <ul>
  <li id="photos1"><a href=""><img src="images/photos/1.jpg" alt="img 1" /></a></li>
  <li id="photos2"><a href=""><img src="images/photos/2.jpg" alt="img 2" /></a></li>
  <li id="photos3"><a href=""><img src="images/photos/3.jpg" alt="img 3" /></a></li>
  <li id="photos4"><a href=""><img src="images/photos/4.jpg" alt="img 4" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="slideshow-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#photos1"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos2"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos3"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#photos4"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'localScroll' script.js:7
```

You forgot to include [jQuery.LocalScroll](http://www.flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html)

download this library, put it to your js folder and insert this into head tag

```
<script src="js/jQuery.LocalScroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man. How did you use the error console? I would love to use it to test my code later on

Comment: I use google chrome browser. To call console on Mac - Cmd + Ctrl + J. Or Tools -> JavaScript Console. It will be useful https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you don't have localScroll plugin on your page.

```
<script src="js/jQuery.LocalScroll.js"></script>
```

by tutorial you supposed to have it.

And then change the event handler of $("#slideshow-nav a") to

```
$("#slideshow-nav a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#slideshow-nav a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

so screen will not go down.